# Facebook api not returning Comments

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

im trying to get some data with the facebook api. Here is my code

```
<?php
include 'src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'     => 'xxx',
    'secret'    => 'xxx',
    'cookie'    => true
));    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $user = $facebook->getUser();

        if($user)
        {
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me/statuses');
            echo "<pre>", print_r($user_profile), "</pre>";

            echo "<a href=logout.php>Logout</a>";
        }
        else
        {
            $login_url_params = array(
                'scope' => 'publish_stream,read_stream,offline_access,manage_pages'
             );

            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($login_url_params);

            //redirect to the login URL on facebook
            header("Location: {$login_url}");
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when i `print_r($user_profile)` it shows all the data that is supposed to come with `$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me/statuses');` but it doesn't show the comments associated with the status.  I tried this in the `Graph API Explorer` and it works fine (shows all of the data), but in my code when i run it; it doesn't get the comments.

Any idea on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me/feed');
```